# Deleting rows from a Data Extension without having to copy the entire table to a temp table

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, import

On a daily basis, I have to remove some rows from my **Customers** Data Extension. This cannot be done via the *Data Retention Policy* since the IDs are provided by a database (and saved in a separate Data Extension) and this does not depend on how old data is.

As far as I know, there is no straightforward way of deleting rows from a Data Extention e.g. running a `DELETE FROM` query inside a *SQL Query Activity*. So the suggested solution so far is to copy all the data inside the **Customers** DE into a temp DE like **CustomersTemp** and then using another *SQL Query Activity* to exclude the rows we don't want and "Overwrite" **Customers** using that query.

E.g.

```
SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, ..., FieldN
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM DeletedCustomer)
```

But for a Data Extension with millions of rows, this looks like too much work. I am wondering how I can make this process easier on the server.

Is the current solution better than overwriting the entire Data Extension every day? Because as of today, I am only using delta files (only the modified rows for the last 30 days) to update my Data Extensions to save time and resource.

If you have a better alternative in place, I would appreciate if you shared with me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at deleting Millions of rows then using a staging table may be the most optimized way, however for smaller volumes
SSJS Activities may be able to help - for example using WSProxy (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_delete.htm) would allow you to do all the same actions you would be able to do via SOAP - this would mean doing delete with primary keys
Alternative would be using the deletedata function (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionDeleteData.htm) which is purely value based.

Comment: When you say "using a staging table", does it mean the same solution I explained above? I will get into the nitty-gritty of SSJS if this does not work. But just to make sure my solution is not terrible.

Comment: Hey, yep same thing. It's not the worst idea and if you are deleting Millions of rows per day it would likely be the better option than using SSJS